# Highstocks candlesticksandvolume datetime

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have used High-Stocks chart.I want the graph's x-axis date format to be represented in week or month or year depending upon the user choice(given in radio button). How can i do it?. 
 a link! .In this i have kept the radio button for weeks,months,years.

Comment: My code is in https://jsfiddle.net/hdt9yqff/1

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning you need to apply a name for you inputs and remove id (in html you should not use elements with the same ID).

Next step is catch click event on radio buttons and extract extremes on xAxis (min and max). If you have that, you should calculate how many days you need defer from last point (time in milisecond) and call setExtremes to apply new range.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hdt9yqff/2/

```
$('input[name="crange"]').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            extremes = xAxis.getExtremes(),
            index = parseFloat($(this).val()),
            range;

        switch (index) {
            case 0: //week
                range = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //7 days 
                break;
            case 1:
                range = 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //31 days 
                break;
            case 2:
                 range = 3 * 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //quark days 
                break;
            case 3: //year
                 range = 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //1 year 
                break;
        }

        xAxis.setExtremes(extremes.max - range, extremes.max);
    });
```

Comment: Some months have 30 days and some months have 31 days and so on.. How can i identify it.I waht to display only that moths data in chart if 1 month is choosen